# Remove attribute for every element on my page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using a custom Primefaces/JSF based framework for my page. Unfortunately, by default it sets many unwanted title attributes, so now my last resort is a short JavaScript that's embedded on every page that clears the title attribute of every element (that has one set, at least).

Is there a smarter method than simply iterating through all elements and setting the attribute to null for each?

Answer (score 2):

You can target only the elements that have `target` attributes by using an [attribute presence selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#attribute-representation) (`[title]`):

```
for (const element of document.querySelectorAll("[title]")) {
    element.removeAttribute("title");
}
```

That does involve creating an interim `NodeList`, which you could avoid with a recursive tree traversal. Recursive tree traversal sounds complicated, but it isn't particularly:

```
function removeTitle(element) {
    element.removeAttribute("title");
    for (const child of element.children) {
        removeTitle(child);
    }
}
removeTitle(document.documentElement);
```

I was tempted to have

```
    if (element.title) { // `title` is a reflected attribute
        element.removeAttribute("title");
    }
```

instead of just

```
    element.removeAttribute("title");
```

...but even though it doesn't look like it, `element.title` is a function call (`title` is an accessor property), so it probably doesn't make sense to do the check. (I'm also probably overthinking it.)

Comment: Thanks, worked flawlessly - even, surprisingly, for dynamic components like table rows.

Comment: @Noel93 - It'll handle the elements in the DOM as of when you run it, so I guess you have it running after those rows have been added. If you need to handle running it again after the DOM is changed, you can use a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for that.

Comment: How would you use the mutation observer? Add the same one to every element? I tried adding it to just the top level document, but this will only catch changes to the direct children.

Comment: No, I'd attach it to the document element (`document.documentElement`) with `subtree: true`. Then loop through any nodes being added (or modified, I suppose) removing `title`. If you run into trouble I suggest posting a question with your attempt and someone will be able to help. :-)